# Entity Framework how to prevent loading tree when child entity returns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a complicated tree structure of my entites, and if i try to access a entity of tree, EF generate very large query with many JOIN's to other one-level childs.
And if i try to return child entity from its DbContext as parent abstract entity,  EF still generating big query. Lazy loading is on.
How can i return child entity without joining another one-level childs?
 [Db Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQNfY.png)
Parent class declaration:

```
public abstract partial class Document : Basics.AccountableGradInfoDbObject
{
    protected Document ()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Child class declaration:

```
 public partial class ChildDocumentOne: Document
{
    public ChildDocumentOne()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

What i try to do:

```
      public static Document GetDocumentById(this MyDbContext ctxt, int docId) //trying to get child entity by PK and return it as parent abstract class
    {
        ...
        switch (docStr.DocumentKind) //entity type found
        {
            case "DocumentOne":
                return MyDbContext.DocumentOneSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == docId); // getting entity from stecified dbcontext
```

As result, generates linq containing about 1500 lines and joining all childs.

Comment: You need to add your code, otherwise it won't be possible to help you.

Comment: I could imagine using class/variables being in native language other than english, but never thought it would be non latin

Comment: load the tables separately and entityframe work will automattically join things on the CLR side